# Cambiar URL en Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy iniciando en **Codeigniter** en el trabajo y me dieron un proyecto de producción, está programado con el Framework de Codeigniter y lo instale en localhost pero me di cuenta que al usarlo la URL no encuentra la ruta.

```
var url_ = "/catalogos/saveGeneralCat";
$.ajax({
    url: url_,
    type: "post",
    data: $("#registroAlmacen").serialize(),
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#overlay").show()
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $("#overlay").hide();
        if (response == "error") {
            swal({
                title: "Error, el registro ya existe!",
                buttonsStyling: false,
                confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-danger"
            });
        }
    },
});
```

Me debería llevar a `http://localhost/sah19/catalogo/saveGeneralCat`
y me lleva a la dirección `http://localhost/catalogo/saveGeneralCat`
como se dan cuenta falta `sah19` que es el nombre del proyecto.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué omite la carpeta del proyecto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/322813/por-qu%c3%a9-omite-la-carpeta-del-proyecto)

Answer (score -1):

Ya revisaste el archivo de configuración? tambien puedes buscar información como Config Class

La dirección dentro de las carpeta de tu proyecto es:

application/config/config.php

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que configurar la `base_url()`, para eso tienes que ir al archivo **config.php** que se encuentra en: `application/config/config.php`.

Dentro encontraras `$config['base_url']` y lo defines con tu URL:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sah19/';
```

Y tu `Ajax` quedaría así:

```
var url_ = "catalogos/saveGeneralCat";
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>' + url_,
    type: "post",
    data: $("#registroAlmacen").serialize(),
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#overlay").show()
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $("#overlay").hide();
        if (response == "error") {
            swal({
                title: "Error, el registro ya existe!",
                buttonsStyling: false,
                confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-danger"
            });
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: ¿Supones que el código ajax debería de ir en una vista? Se perdería el MVC, sugiero que se declare de manera global la variable por javascript para que pueda ser usado en cualquier parte de las vistas habidas y por haber o en cualquier script (se recomienda crearse fuera al nivel de la raíz del proyecto en una carpeta assets). Por otro lado, sí se puede usar de manera relativa en ajax las peticiones, estás deben de ir a un controlador y método en específico y la solución para esta pregunta no creo que vaya enfocado a lo que tiene configurado en su config.php como base_url.

Comment: Pero que dices wtf, en que momento se pierde el MVC... Si simplemente estás creando algo de Ajax en la vista no por eso se pierde el MVC lol.

Comment: Además de que no veo cómo justificar la respuesta ampliamente, viendo que ésto, evidentemente no es una respuesta válida, agrego a mi comentario anterior que combinar php con javascript  en un mismo archivo es una muy mala práctica, más en codeigniter. Imagínate tener que mantener un archivo en donde habita CSS, SQL, PHP y Javascript juntos. Hacer esto muestra una falta de conocimientos sobre para qué funciona cada lenguaje y el cómo usar correctamente MVC, específicamente en codeigniter.

Comment: Jajaja, claro si tu lo dices, sobre todo en un mismo archivo Sql, Css y todo... En fin te dejo  copado con lo que piensas. Nisiquiera se en que momento yo mencione que todo iba en un mismo archivo... No se de donde sacaste eso. Si te fijas dice tu Ajax quedar así. Jamás dije tu vista con tu Javascript y toda esa boberia que mencionas.